# Cache Hessian services results base on the service name and parameters

Tags: java, caching, hessian

I have to call to get many data from Hessian services, the services are quite slow. Because the Hessian calls do not update data and the results are rarely changed. I wonder is there anyway to cache the result base on the service name and parameters in a predefined time. I use Hessian with Spring.
Thanks,
Loc

Answer (score 0):

I would build a cache and when you have a cache miss, then ask the Hessian service.